# aggregating single column data into a dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, dplyr

i have a table with the same key values like this

| Measure | element | unit | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measurment N° 000001 - A | NA | NA | NA |
| Point 0000000101 | NA | NA | NA |
| Station alpha | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | 11-Jan-2018 |
| NA | Parameter A | mg | 5 |
| NA | Parameter C | mg | 6 |
| NA | Parameter E | mg | 8 |
| NA | Parameter F | mg | 3 |
| NA | Parameter G | mg | 4 |
| Measurment N° 000003 - A | NA | NA | NA |
| Point 0000000121 | NA | NA | NA |
| Station bravo | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | 19-Jun-2019 |
| NA | Parameter A | mg | 1 |
| NA | Parameter B | mg | 9 |
| NA | Parameter D | g | 5 |
| NA | Parameter F | mg | 6 |
| NA | Parameter G | mg | 3 |
| Measurment N° 000003 - B | NA | NA | NA |
| Point 0000000122 | NA | NA | NA |
| Station charlie | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | 17-Jan-2020 |
| NA | Parameter A | mg | 9 |
| NA | Parameter E | mg | 5 |
| NA | Parameter F | mg | 3 |

```
df <- as_tibble(list(measure = c('Measurment N° 000001 - A', 'Point 0000000101', 'Station alpha', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,'Measurment N° 000003 - A', 'Point 0000000121', 'Station bravo', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,'Measurment N° 000003 - B', 'Point 0000000122', 'Station Charlie', NA, NA, NA, NA),
                      element = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 'Parameter A', 'Parameter C','Parameter E','Parameter F','Parameter G',NA, NA, NA, NA, 'Parameter A', 'Parameter B','Parameter D','Parameter F','Parameter G',NA, NA, NA, NA, 'Parameter A', 'Parameter E','Parameter F'),
                      unit = c(NA, NA , NA, NA, 'mg', 'mg', 'mg', 'mg', 'mg',NA, NA , NA, NA, 'mg', 'mg', 'g', 'mg', 'mg',NA, NA , NA, NA, 'mg', 'mg', 'mg'),
                      value = c(NA, NA , NA, '11-Jan-2018', 5, 6, 8, 3, 4,NA, NA , NA, '19-Jun-2019', 1, 9, 5, 6, 3,NA, NA , NA, '17-Jan-2020', 9, 5, 3)))
```

i have to get the data by point,measurement station like this :

| Measurement | point | station | date | Parameter A | Parameter B | Parameter C | Parameter D | Parameter E | Parameter F | Parameter G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | mg | mg | mg | g | mg | mg | mg |
| Measurment N° 000001 - A | Point 0000000101 | Station alpha | 11-Jan-2018 | 5 | NA | 6 | NA | 8 | 3 | 4 |
| Measurment N° 000003 - A | Point 0000000121 | Station bravo | 19-Jun-2019 | 1 | 9 | NA | 5 | NA | 6 | 3 |
| Measurment N° 000003 - B | Point 0000000122 | Station Charlie | 17-Jan-2020 | 9 | NA | NA | NA | 5 | 3 | NA |

i am looking for a way to aggregate this data using R or pandas

Comment: By expecting `"mg"` as a *row* in the frame, you are guaranteeing that all of your numbers will be strings, not numbers. R doesn't do two-header-rows like other tools. I suggest to have numbers stored as numbers, either encode the units in the column name or, if they are not all the same, stored them in another set of columns.

Comment: i can forgo that units line , it's not important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pandas you can create a unique identifier for chunks of data by flagging rows that start with `'Measurment'`. `pivot` gets all the parameters into a wide format for each chunk, and groupby will split the measurement/date information into separate fields for each chunk. Then we join all the data together.

The units will cause issues with dtypes the way you specified so either don't include them, or see the alternative after the first chunk of code which will keep the Series as numeric dtypes.

```
df['idx'] = df['measure'].str.startswith('Measurment', na=False).astype(int).cumsum()

params = (df[df.element.notnull()].pivot(index='idx', columns='element', values='value')
            .rename_axis(columns=None, index=None))
units = df.groupby('element').unit.first()

# Add a row of units at the top, or ignore this completely. 
params = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([params.columns.map(units)], columns=params.columns, index=[0]),
                    params])

info = df.groupby('idx').agg(Measurement=('measure', 'first'),
                             point=('measure', lambda x: x.iloc[1]),
                             station=('measure', lambda x: x.iloc[2]),
                             date=('value', 'first'))

result = pd.concat([info, params], axis=1)
```

---

```
                Measurement             point          station         date Parameter A Parameter B Parameter C Parameter D Parameter E Parameter F Parameter G
0                       NaN               NaN              NaN          NaN          mg          mg          mg           g          mg          mg          mg
1  Measurment N° 000001 - A  Point 0000000101    Station alpha  11-Jan-2018           5         NaN           6         NaN           8           3           4
2  Measurment N° 000003 - A  Point 0000000121    Station bravo  19-Jun-2019           1           9         NaN           5         NaN           6           3
3  Measurment N° 000003 - B  Point 0000000122  Station Charlie  17-Jan-2020           9         NaN         NaN         NaN           5           3         NaN
```

---

But as pointed out in the comments, requiring the units to be values in those Series will create `object` columns which makes subsequent calculations difficult. We can instead use a `MultiIndex`, which the concat will flatten to a tuple. So instead of the line of code that `"Add a row of units at top"` use

```
params.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([params.columns, params.columns.map(units)])
```

which after the rest of the code results in:

```
                Measurement             point          station         date (Parameter A, mg) (Parameter B, mg) (Parameter C, mg) (Parameter D, g) (Parameter E, mg) (Parameter F, mg) (Parameter G, mg)
1  Measurment N° 000001 - A  Point 0000000101    Station alpha  11-Jan-2018                 5               NaN                 6              NaN                 8                 3                 4
2  Measurment N° 000003 - A  Point 0000000121    Station bravo  19-Jun-2019                 1                 9               NaN                5               NaN                 6                 3
3  Measurment N° 000003 - B  Point 0000000122  Station Charlie  17-Jan-2020                 9               NaN               NaN              NaN                 5                 3               NaN
```

Comment: in my file who has a lot of data, in params i ran into the problem of having the same index due to measurements having the same name , so while pivoting it returns ' Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Comment: the column where i have unique values is the 'point' column

Answer (score 2):

I'll use a hybrid base/tidyverse set of code.

The base portion is for cutting out each group of rows. We can grep for `^Meas` and assign groups based on that.

```r
cumsum(grepl("^Meas", dat$Measure))
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3

func <- function(x) {
  vals <- na.omit(unlist(x[1:4,c("Measure", "value")]))
  stopifnot(length(vals) == 4L)
  left <- setNames(
    as.data.frame(matrix(vals, nrow = 1)),
    c("Measure", "point", "station", "date"))
  right <- as.data.frame(matrix(x$value[-(1:4)], nrow = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, x$element[-(1:4)])))
  cbind(left, right)
}

func(dat[1:9,])
#                    Measure            point       station        date Parameter A Parameter C Parameter E Parameter F Parameter G
# 1 Measurment N° 000001 - A Point 0000000101 Station alpha 11-Jan-2018           5           6           8           3           4
```

From here, it's grouping and combining. While we can do row-wise combination of a list of frames using `do.call(rbind, ..)`, it takes a bit more work when elements do not have the same columns and in the same order.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(grepl("^Meas", Measure))) %>%
  do(func(.)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Measure, point, station, date, sort(colnames(.)), -grp)
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#   Measure                  point            station         date        `Parameter A` `Parameter B` `Parameter C` `Parameter D` `Parameter E` `Parameter F` `Parameter G`
#   <chr>                    <chr>            <chr>           <chr>       <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        
# 1 Measurment N° 000001 - A Point 0000000101 Station alpha   11-Jan-2018 5             <NA>          6             <NA>          8             3             4            
# 2 Measurment N° 000003 - A Point 0000000121 Station bravo   19-Jun-2019 1             9             <NA>          5             <NA>          6             3            
# 3 Measurment N° 000003 - B Point 0000000122 Station charlie 17-Jan-2020 9             <NA>          <NA>          <NA>          5             3             <NA>
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Measure = c("Measurment N° 000001 - A", "Point 0000000101", "Station alpha", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Measurment N° 000003 - A", "Point 0000000121", "Station bravo", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Measurment N° 000003 - B", "Point 0000000122", "Station charlie", NA, NA, NA, NA), element = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Parameter A", "Parameter C", "Parameter E", "Parameter F", "Parameter G", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Parameter A", "Parameter B", "Parameter D", "Parameter F", "Parameter G", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Parameter A", "Parameter E", "Parameter F"), unit = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", NA, NA, NA, NA, "mg", "mg", "g", "mg", "mg", NA, NA, NA, NA, "mg", "mg", "mg"), value = c(NA, NA, NA, "11-Jan-2018", "5", "6", "8", "3", "4", NA, NA, NA, "19-Jun-2019", "1", "9", "5", "6", "3", NA, NA, NA, "17-Jan-2020", "9", "5", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
expected <- structure(list(Measurement = c("Measurment N° 000001 - A", "Measurment N° 000003 - A", "Measurment N° 000003 - B"), point = c("Point 0000000101", "Point 0000000121", "Point 0000000122"), station = c("Station alpha", "Station bravo", "Station Charlie"), date = c("11-Jan-2018", "19-Jun-2019", "17-Jan-2020"), Parameter.A = c(5L, 1L, 9L), Parameter.B = c(NA, 9L, NA),     Parameter.C = c(6L, NA, NA), Parameter.D = c(NA, 5L, NA),     Parameter.E = c(8L, NA, 5L), Parameter.F = c(3L, 6L, 3L),     Parameter.G = c(4L, 3L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of crude, but it works

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% select(-unit) %>%
  mutate(element = case_when(str_detect(Measure, "Measurment") | 
                           str_detect(Measure, "Point") |
                           str_detect(Measure, "Station") ~ Measure, 
                         TRUE ~ element),
         Measure = case_when(str_detect(Measure, "Measurment") ~ Measure,
                              TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  fill(Measure) %>% mutate(element = ifelse(is.na(element), "date", element)) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(element, "Measurment")) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), element, value),
         element = case_when(str_detect(element, "Point") ~ "Point",
                             str_detect(element, "Station") ~ "Station",
                             TRUE ~ element)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = element, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 3 x 11
  Measure Point Station date  `Parameter A` `Parameter C` `Parameter E` `Parameter F` `Parameter G`
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        
1 Measur~ Poin~ Statio~ 11-J~ 5             6             8             3             4            
2 Measur~ Poin~ Statio~ 19-J~ 1             NA            NA            6             3            
3 Measur~ Poin~ Statio~ 17-J~ 9             NA            5             3             NA           
# ... with 2 more variables: `Parameter B` <chr>, `Parameter D` <chr>
```

sample dput

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Measure = c("Measurment N° 000001 - A", "Point 0000000101", 
"Station alpha", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Measurment N° 000003 - A", 
"Point 0000000121", "Station bravo", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Measurment N° 000003 - B", "Point 0000000122", "Station charlie", 
NA, NA, NA, NA), element = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Parameter A", "Parameter C", 
"Parameter E", "Parameter F", "Parameter G", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Parameter A", "Parameter B", "Parameter D", "Parameter F", "Parameter G", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Parameter A", "Parameter E", "Parameter F"), 
    unit = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "mg", "mg", "g", "mg", "mg", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "mg", "mg", "mg"), value = c(NA, NA, NA, "11-Jan-18", "5", 
    "6", "8", "3", "4", NA, NA, NA, "19-Jun-19", "1", "9", "5", 
    "6", "3", NA, NA, NA, "17-Jan-20", "9", "5", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```